# How to do I get object keys by a pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an object with named keys:

```
var names = {
  "Peter Pan": {...},
  "Peter Parker": {...},
  "Tony Stark": {...},
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to get all keys by a pattern eg. all keys having Peter in it?

The case is that I want to have all the filtered keys in an array eg:

```
var filteredNames: [
  "Peter Pan",
  "Peter Parker",
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can easily do it by looping over the keys yourself:

```
var filtered_keys = function(obj, filter) {
  var key, keys = [];
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && filter.test(key)) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}
// example:
var filteredNames = filtered_keys(names, /Peter/); // second parameter is a javascript regex object, so for exemple for case insensitive you would do /Peter/i
```

---

**ES6**

```
let filtered_keys = (obj, filter) => {
  let key, keys = []
  for (key in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && filter.test(key))
      keys.push(key)
  return keys
}

// example:
let filteredNames = filtered_keys(names, /Peter/)
```

Comment: +1 for using *hasOwnProperty*. If an exact match of plain text is required, a regular expression isn't needed (the string will be converted to a RegExp by *match*). If a regular epxression is used, *test* is more suitable as it is a simpler algorithm and returns a boolean (e.g. `filter.test(key)`), whereas *match* returns an array that will be type converted to boolean.

Answer (score 30):

```
var filteredNames = Object.keys(names).filter((name) => /Peter/.test(name));
```

Comment: If this code is running in a browser, be aware that `forEach` and `filter` are unsupported in IE8 and lower.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it case sensitive:

```
var filteredNames = [];

for( name in names ) {
    if( name.indexOf( "Peter" ) > -1 ) {
        filteredNames.push( name );
    }
}
```

If not:

```
var filteredNames = [];

for( name in names ) {
    if( /peter/gi.test( name ) ) {
        filteredNames.push( name );
    }
}
```

Comment: You will also need to use hasOwnProperty() in the for in, otherwise you might have keys selected from higher up in the prototype chain (unless that's what you want, of course).

Comment: @Lepidosteus: Except that it's an object literal, so there won't be any enumerable properties up the chain unless you extend `Object.prototype`, in which case your code *ought to break* so you can correct that flaw.

Comment: You are entirely right, but I was thinking more along the lines of his code being an example while his real use case could be something where names has prototype properties. Having seen so many misuses of for in in production code, I tend to get the shield up before being hit, so to speak.

Comment: @Lepidosteus: Yes, if it's the case that it is not an object literal, but rather the product of a custom constructor with enumerable properties on its prototype, then that may be necessary *if* those properties should be excluded. It could be that the prototype carries defaults that ought to be enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the JavaScript Array prototype, like so:

```
Array.prototype.regex_search = function(pattern) {
  var returns = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if(this[i].match(pattern) {
      returns.push(i);
    }
  }
  if(returns.length) {
    return returns;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Now I haven't actually tested this code but this would give all arrays you create in JavaScript a method .regex_search which takes an argument 'pattern'. This will either return false when no matches are found or an array of indices when elements match.

You could then iterate over this array and take those indices from the original array.

Comment: He is iterating over an object's keys, not an array. Also, I wouldn't recommand editing the prototype chain of native objects such as Array.